# I have installed Oracl virtualbox in ubuntu 16.04, I want to use windows 10 in virtualbox, I have tried much, but not done, please help?

Tags: virtualbox

I am getting everytime this error, please please do help
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows10.

```
The virtual machine 'Windows10' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}


Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

Comment: Read the error: `Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'`

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

The key part of the error message is this section:

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.

You don't have the VirtualBox driver installed. So, run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
sudo modprobe vboxrv
```